# Fluent NHibernate problem querying against DateTime property

Tags: linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to retrieve a row using a where clause against a DateTime.

Note: `Query` is an `IQueryable` from `ISession.Query` extension.

```
var results = Query
   .Where(row => row.TimeStampUtc == timeStampUtc);
```

**This returns no results.**

```
var results = Query.ToList()
    .Where(row => row.TimeStampUtc == timeStampUtc);
```

**This returns results.** (By using ToList() im avoiding the NHibernate query provider).

What trick am I missing?

**Update:**

SQL profiler tells me that its querying for

```
where row.TimeStampUtc = '2011-01-28T09:28:55.00' /* @p0 */
```

but the actual column value is `'2011-01-28 09:28:55.987'` hence no matches.

Somewhere during mapping (presumably reading) I am  losing the sub-second data.

Comment: How is the column defined on the db, what db is it?

Comment: SQL2008. The column is auto mapped. I am now investigating CustomType(DateTime2), which would work but it seems to not work because the column is also part of a CompositeId defintion...need to find way to do CompositeId while at same time acknowledging CustomType

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the fact the column was used as part of a `CompositeId`.

I could not use `CustomType` on the column alone, because its ignored if the column is also defined as part of a `CompositeId`.

The solution is the use the `Type` method on the `KeyProperty` definition.

```
  mapping.CompositeId()
                .KeyProperty(x => x.Name)
                .KeyProperty(x => x.TimeStampUtc, k => k.Type("DateTime2"));
```